# How to set data type of enum class?

Tags: java, c#, enums

I am creating an enum class in java, which is already created in .NET.

This is .NET code.

```
public enum Bezel : byte
        {
            Flashing,
            SolidOn,
            None = 254
        }
```

And this is Java code i am trying.

```
public enum Bezel {

        Flashing,
        SolidOn,
        None = 254
    }
```

In the .NET code, they are extending "byte". So, how can we do the same in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums in Java and .NET are *very* different. In .NET, they're just named numbers, basically. In Java they're a fixed set of objects - which you can give extra behaviour etc.

Also, the C# code isn't "extending" `byte` - it's just using `byte` as the underlying type. The nearest equivalent Java code would be something like:

```
public enum Bezel {
    // Note different naming convention in Java
    FLASHING((byte) 0),
    SOLID_ON((byte) 1),
    NONE((byte) 254);

    private final byte value;

    private Bezel(byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that if you print out `Bezel.NONE.getValue()`, it will print -2, because Java's `byte` type is signed whereas it's unsigned in C#. There's no unsigned byte type in Java - but you could always use `short` or `int` instead, to cover the 0-255 range (and more, of course).

You may *also* want a method to retrieve a `Bezel` given its value - something you could do in C# just by casting. We don't know how you're going to use the enum though.

Answer (score 2):

Enums in java are sets of objects, not sets of constants as they are in C#.
So, you need to write your enum in java like this:

```
public enum Bezel 
(
    Flashing(0),
    SolidOn(1),
    None(254);

    public final int value;
    public Bezel( int value )
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
)
```

Then, when you need the actual value, do this:

```
Bezel b = ...;
int value = b.value;
```